# adjustOHLC - need solution to loop through character vector of tickers

Tags: r, lapply, quantmod, financial

What I want to do is fairly easy but I haven't been able to figure it out. I thought I could do something similar to that outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8562197/quantmod-save-tickers-to-files-in-a-loop-or-lapply)

I have a character vector of tickers that are xts OHLC objects returned by `getSymbols`. I want to loop through each ticker in symbols and pass the symbol to `adjustOHLC` to adjust for splits:

```
symbols = c("FCX", "SPY")

for(symbol in symbols){
  return(adjustOHLC(symbol,adjust =c("split"), use.Adjusted=FALSE))
}
```

It seems `adjustOHLC` does not *grab* the value of the variable 'symbol':

```
debug: div <- getDividends(symbol.name)
Browse[2]> symbol.name
[1] "symbol"
Browse[2]> 
Error in download.file(paste(yahoo.URL, Symbol.name, "&a=", from.m, "&b=",  : 
  cannot open URL 'http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=symbol&a=0&b=01&c=1970&d=3&e=14&f=2012&g=v&ignore=.csv'
In addition: Warning message:
In download.file(paste(yahoo.URL, Symbol.name, "&a=", from.m, "&b=",  :
  cannot open: HTTP status was '404 Not Found'
```

If I use `get(symbols)` I get the same result (similar approach was used in the link I show at the top of this post):

```
for(symbol in symbols){
  return(adjustOHLC(get(symbol),adjust =c("split"), use.Adjusted=FALSE))
}

debug: div <- getDividends(symbol.name)
Browse[2]> symbol.name
[1] "get(symbol)"
Browse[2]> 
Error in download.file(paste(yahoo.URL, Symbol.name, "&a=", from.m, "&b=",  : 
  cannot open URL 'http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=get(symbol)&a=0&b=01&c=1970&d=3&e=14&f=2012&g=v&ignore=.csv'
In addition: Warning message:
In download.file(paste(yahoo.URL, Symbol.name, "&a=", from.m, "&b=",  :
  cannot open: HTTP status was '404 Not Found'
```

I thought I could also make use of `lapply` to make this faster but think I'm stuck with the above issue first.

`lapply(symbols, function(x) adjustOHLC(x, adjust=c("split"), use.Adjusted=FALSE) )`

Seems easy enough - I apologize if this is so trivial. Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `x` argument of `adjustOHLC` should be an xts object.  So, you need to use `get` to get it.  But, if the yahoo ticker symbols is different than the name of the xts object (`get(symbol)` in this case), then you need to use the `symbol.name` argument.  Also, you'll need to assign the values inside your for loop because adjustOHLC does not "auto.assign" like `getSymbols` does.

```
symbols = c("FCX", "SPY")
getSymbols(symbols, src='yahoo')
for(symbol in symbols){
  assign(symbol,adjustOHLC(get(symbol, pos=.GlobalEnv), symbol.name=symbol, 
                           adjust=c("split"), use.Adjusted=FALSE))
}
```

Since you mentioned using lapply, here's how you could use it

```
adjusted.list <- lapply(symbols, function(x) {
  adjustOHLC(get(x, pos=.GlobalEnv), symbol.name=x, adjust=c("split"), 
             use.Adjusted=FALSE)
})
names(adjusted.list) <- symbols
```